# String manipulation in less/scss?

Tags: css, sass, less

Using less functions is it possible to convert to `t r b l` to `t l b r`?

```
.foo{
    border: fn(1px 2px 3px 4px)
}
```

Comment: No, there's no built-in function like this. There's "custom functions" [plugin](http://lesscss.org/usage/#plugins-list-of-less-plugins) though. (And btw, where do you see a "string" in your code above?)

Comment: And, btw, what language are you writing in? Sass or Less? These are not synonyms nor clones (C++ also has variables and functions and you can use it to process CSS as well but you don't add [cpp] tag here, are you?). Different languages usually assume different answers, so please be specific.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using mixin:

```
.border (@t, @l, @b, @r) {
    border-top:@t;
    border-left:@l;
    border-bottom:@b;
    border-right:@r;
}

.foo  {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    .border(2px, 1px, 3px, 4px);
}
```

This compiles to:

```
.foo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top: 2px;
  border-left: 1px;
  border-bottom: 3px;
  border-right: 4px;
}
```

**UPDATE**

As proposed by @seven-phases-max, here is a more efficient solution:

```
.border(@t, @l, @b, @r) {
    border: @t @r @b @l;
}

.foo  {
    .border(1px, 2px, 3px, 4px);
}
```

Which compiles to:

```
.foo {
  border: 1px 4px 3px 2px;
}
```

Comment: Edited and improved. Thanks.

Comment: I would change the parameter order to be `@t @r @b @l` so that its the same order as the css border shorthand.

Comment: But the OP's question is precisely a method to invert the order.